# How do I achieve this in Folium?

Tags: python, visualization, folium

I am working on plotting the major earthquakes using Folium. I am able to plot all the instances, about 25000 of them. But the map starts looking very clumsy. I have used the following code:

```
map1 = folium.Map(location=[80., -180], zoom_start=1)
def color(magnitude):
if magnitude<6:
    col='green'
elif [(magnitude>6)&(magnitude<7.5)]:
    col='yellow'
else:
    col='red'
return col
fg=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Earthquake Locations")
for latitude,longitude,magnitude in zip(earthquakes['Latitude'][:30],earthquakes['Longitude'][:30],earthquakes['Magnitude'][:30]):
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[latitude,longitude],popup=(folium.Popup(magnitude)),icon=folium.Icon(color=color(magnitude))))
map1.add_child(fg)
```

Now I want to make the plot look something like the first plot in the following R notebook:
[Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/verawe/earthquakes-leaflet-highcharter-visualizations).

Can someone help me in achieving such a plot, where in the individual points are clustered and as we zoom, the points show up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  `MarkerCluster` is what you're after

Give this a whirl

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

map1 = folium.Map(location=[80., -180], zoom_start=1)

def color(magnitude):
    if magnitude<6:
        col='green'
    elif [(magnitude>6)&(magnitude<7.5)]:
        col='yellow'
    else:
        col='red'
    return col

map1.add_child(MarkerCluster(locations=list(zip(earthquakes['Latitude'], 
                                 earthquakes['Longitude'])),
                                 popups=earthquakes['Magnitude'].astype(str),
                                 icons=[color(m) for m in earthquakes['Magnitude']]))

map1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code by Bob Haffer also worked. I tried to tweak around and wrote another piece of code:

```
import folium
import folium.plugins
map1 = folium.Map(width=1000,height=500,location=[80, -180],tiles='CartoDB dark_matter',zoom_start=1)
def color(magnitude):
if magnitude<6:
    col='green'
else: 
    col='red'
return col
marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map1)
for point in locationlist.index:
    folium.Marker(list(locationlist.loc[point].values),popup='Magnitude:'+str(locationlist_pop[point]),icon=folium.Icon(color=color(locationlist_pop[point]))).add_to(marker_cluster)
marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map1)
map1
```

[image: Output]